# Eclipse Jetty appears to be unusable

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed the Eclipse Jetty plugin version 3.9.0 into Eclipse Mars. Unfortunately, while it shows as installed, I do not see any Jetty- related functions appearing in my IDE! It is as if the plugin is dead weight!

I have looked through Eclipse and Jetty tutorials trying to find something that tells me how to access the Jetty plugin in Eclipse. I am finding some nice Jetty tutorials, but nothing about how to access and use the actual plugin. In fact, Jetty as a container doesn't even appear in the list of Servlet containers that are available to Eclipse.

Could someone please either tell me how to use this plugin or point me to somewhere where I can learn? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about [Eclipse Jetty Integration](http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/), all the documentation you need to use it is right there.